# import org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement not found? which jar to import foe this?

Tags: java, jar, single-sign-on, importerror, axis

I have opened the jws file of StatelessAuthenticationSSOToken, sample code availabe in Oracle Repository.But even after importing all the libraries it says "Import org.apache.axis.message.* not found".I already have axis.jar in my classpath beside other Apache axis1.4 libraries.
Whic other library or jars are required to be imported

Answer (score 0):

If you have the jars on your classpath, check the order. You might have to change it under the **Order & Export tab.**